# Why is the Voltage after Inductor discharging, the Voltage 24V?

Tags: mosfet, inductor, schottky

As seen in the schematic, V2 ([SUM75N06-09L](https://www.vishay.com/docs/72037/72037.pdf)) is switched off and then L1 is discharging through D1 and D2. After discharging the voltage at node vn003 (marked in schematic) is at 24V. Can anyone please explain?

I am new here, if any missing information or if i am understanding something wrong, please correct me.
Thank you in advance.
[image][image]

Comment: Where is D1 ? NB: 1N914 seems to be very "low" in specifications (only 200 mA ?) ...

Comment: Can you explain what is it that you are actually asking to explain? Because, if the voltage is 24V, what are you surprised about it, what do you expect it to be and why? Also, you have a simulator, you should be to simulate why it is 24V?

Comment: seems like it could be current leaking through D5 and D2 (they're identical so if it was that, then the voltage would be half of the supply (48V/2=24V)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The leakage through D2 & D3 form a voltage divider on your 48V supply, so the midpoint node is at 24V when both FETs are off.  Add a 1M pull-down resistor to ground, and it will get pretty close to gnd.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the FETs, you simply have a load (possibly ideal inductor with no resistance) in series with two reverse biased Schottky diodes.

Schottky diodes, among with other components, are not ideal. The diodes will pass reverse leakage current through them when reverse biased.

In the simulator, the components are identical with no manufacturing tolerances, so at any given reverse voltage over each diode, they leak identical current. And since two diodes have 48V over them and they have identical leakage model, it means there must be identical voltage over both diodes to leak identical current.

So since the reverse bias voltage sums to 48V, there must be 24V over each diode to leak equal current.

If you put a current probe on the component pins, you are likely to find leakage current through diodes.

Datasheet tells at 24V the leakage should be in the range of 100 to 200 nA at 25°C. It could be about 2 mA at 150°C.

When you buy real world components and use them, they are not identical due to manufacturing tolerances and will have non-identical voltage over them at the leakage current, so the voltage could be anything between 0 and 48V depending on how much leakage each diode has in relation to each other.

It may also be hard to measure in real life, as if the leakage is 200nA, even putting a 10x scope probe with 10Mohm input impedance will even load the voltage down from 24V down to only 2V.